# Mock Setup() does not work when setting multiple properties

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have this `Moq`:

```
readonly Mock<IHeartbeat> _mockIHeartbeat = new Mock<IHeartbeat>();

[Fact]
public async Task TestWatermarkCheck()
{
    WatermarkOffsets watermarkOffsets = new WatermarkOffsets(1, 10);
    Offset offset = new Offset(5);
    _mockIHeartbeat .Setup(x => x.GetWatermarks()).Returns(watermarkOffsets);
    _mockIHeartbeat .Setup(x => x.GetOffset()).Returns(offset);
    HealthCheckContext context = new HealthCheckContext();
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default;
    Watermark watermark = new Watermark(_mockIHeartbeat.Object);
    HealthCheckResult watermarkHealthCheckResult = await watermark.CheckHealthAsync(context, cancellationToken);
watermarkHealthCheckResult.Status.ToString().Should().Be(HealthCheckResult.Healthy().Status.ToString());
    watermarkHealthCheckResult.Description.ToString().Should().Be("Low: 1 High: 10 Offset: 5");
}
```

This is the SUT:

```
public class CheckKafkaWatermark : IHealthCheck
{
    private readonly IHeartbeatCheckHealthHandler _healthHandler;

    public CheckKafkaWatermark(IHeartbeatCheckHealthHandler healthHandler)
    {
        _healthHandler = healthHandler;
    }

    public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(
        HealthCheckContext context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Healthy($"Low: {_healthHandler.GetWatermarks().Low.ToString()} High: {_healthHandler.GetWatermarks().High.ToString()} Offset: {HealthHandler.GetOffset().Value.ToString()}"));
    }
}
```

With this `_mockIHeartbeat.Setup(x => x.GetOffset().Returns(offset)` does not appear to get set. I.E. it always appears as 0.

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Do you miss close `)` in setup lignes?

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake in the code I posted here. I edited it now. The issue remains though.

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear exactly what you're asking. Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: How does it appear to not get set. What did you do and what actually happened?

Comment: I amended the question to include the full test.

Comment: What does _"does not appear to get set"_ mean? Can you read [ask] and paint us a full picture, as explained on [mre]? If `CheckHealthAsync()` calls `IHeartbeat.GetOffsetPosition()` and returns that in `HealthCheckResult.Description`, all should just work as intended. If not, you need to show more code, explain what you expect to see and tell what you actually observe.

Comment: @runnerpaul In the test snippet you have `GetOffsetPosition` and in the last snippet you have `GetOffset`

Comment: @runnerpaul Can you include the subject under test as well?

Comment: @runnerpaul the subject under test would be the class that is using the healthcheck mock. Looks like `Watermark` is the subject.

Comment: Have you tried to mock only just one of the `GetXYZ` methods? Have you tried to change the ordering of the setup calls? Do they produce the same result?

Comment: The code I added to the question is the SUT `using Watermark = Healthchecks.CheckKafkaWatermark `. Switching the ordering of setup calls makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had this line in my SUT:

```
return await Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Healthy($"Low: {_healthHandler.GetWatermarks().Low.ToString()} High: {_healthHandler.GetWatermarks().High.ToString()} Offset: {HealthHandler.GetOffset().Value.ToString()}"));
```

I should have had:

```
return await Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Healthy($"Low: {_healthHandler.GetWatermarks().Low.ToString()} High: {_healthHandler.GetWatermarks().High.ToString()} Offset: {_healthHandler.GetOffset().Value.ToString()}"));
```

BTW `ToString()` is redundant here so I changed the line to

```
return await Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Healthy($"Low: {_healthHandler.GetWatermarks().Low} High: {_healthHandler.GetWatermarks().High} Offset: {_healthHandler.GetOffset().Value}"));
```